# How to access global angular object in isolated scope of a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I need to call angular.isString() method in html. But I don't know how to access it. My solution is to add a controller property and bind angular object to the isolated scope. It's quite strange! I'm wondering if there is a better way to do that?

Javscript:

```
    App.directive "tfsTaskDetails", ()->
         restrict: 'AE'
          replace: true
          templateUrl: '../../templates/task_details.html'
          scope:
               task: '='
          controller: ($scope)->
         $scope.angular = angular
```

html:

```
  <p ng-if="angular.isString(task.name)">task.name</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of exposing the entire `angular` object, I would probably just expose the function you want:

```
$scope.isString = angular.isString
```

Which you can use as:

```
<p ng-if="isString(task.name)">task.name</p>
```